# How to calculate Stress-strain curve of graphene or any 2D materials (including elastic and plastic region)

Tags: stress-strain

I would like to know how I can get the graph below. In most of the papers, they got stress-strain curves like in picture (1):

[image]

On the other hand, my stress-strain curve of 2D graphene-like material is shown in picture (2):   How can they get these results? Are there any tricks or what?
For more information, I did everything to get this picture (2), but I could not do that
[image]

Comment: For information, I used Quantum Espresso to calculate the stress-energy.

Comment: The images you show from the papers are for an isotropic 2D strain, but your calculations seem to be uniaxial strain - is that what you intended?